# correct instagram authentication method for web applications (users without instagram account)

Tags: javascript, instagram, instagram-api

I would like to show all the instagram pictures with a specific tag in my wedding site, indipendently of the user that has posted it and without asking to my site users to login into Instagram (they could not have an Instagram account!). What is the best and correct way?

What I'm doing now:

1) I've configured a new client "Wedding" in my personal instagram "Manage Clients" section.

2) I've got a token calling MANUALLY (I mean copy and past ONCE the url in my personal browser) the following URL:

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=client_id_of_my_client_wedding&redirect_uri=redirect_uri_of_my_client_wedding&response_type=token

and logging into Instagram with my personal account once asked by the Instagram login popup window

3) I add in my html page the following javascript:

```
<script>
function myinstagramfunction (json_object)
{
    // I fetch here the json object that contains the info of all the pictures returned
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/<my_wedding_tag>/media/recent?access_token=<token_retrieved_in_step_2>&callback=myinstagramfunction"/>
```

The second script performs a cross-domain call to instagram api using JSONP (JSON with Padding) and calling my local function "myinstagramfunction".

Questions:

a) Is this the correct method and the one officially suggested/allowed by instagram?

b) currently the client Wedding is configured in "Sandbox Mode". Do you suggest to submit it to the approval of instagram or is there something not allowed in my procedure?

please let me know!

thank you

Davide

Answer (score 0):

A solution like https://lightwidget.com/ doesn't fit your needs?

No coding skills needed, just copy and paste.. I think this should work ok for a weeding website.

**EDIT:**

Okay, so try this way:

```
function myinstagramfunction (json_object)
{
    // I fetch here the json object that contains the info of all the pictures returned
    console.log("OK");
}
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "jsonp",
   url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/YOUR_HASHTAG/media/recent?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE&callback=myinstagramfunction',
   success: function (result) {
      console.log(result);
   }
});
```

Remember that Instagram api calls has rate limits.

Comment: Thank you for your message. Unfortunately the widget that you are proposing is not real time integrated but is refreshed daily, that's why it doesn't fit my needs

Comment: your suggestion is a specific use of JSONP using ajax call and I think is very useful, but a part of this I would like to understand if the authentication method I'm using is the correct one for my scenario (I mean using in clear a token retrieved logging into my configured instagram application (client) "Wedding" with my personal instagram account and let the wedding site visitors use this token (that will never change!))